# Qt C++ Display new window centered on old window

Tags: c++, qt, centering

I have QWidget with button. When button is pressed, show new smaller window (Qwidget too). I want then new window is centered horizontal and veritcal on main window. Code which display new window is:

```
QWidget *wdg = new QWidget;
QPushButton *closeBtn = new QPushButton("Close");
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(closeBtn);
wdg->setLayout(layout);
wdg->show();
wdg->resize(400,200);
```

Comment: Style note: you can replace `new QHBoxLayout; [...] wdg->setLayout` with `new QHBoxLayout(wdg)`. The `setLayout` is then unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `move` slot.  For example:

```
QPoint centerPoint = oldWidget->geometry()->center();

newWidget->adjustSize();
newWidget->move(centerPoint.x() - newWidget->width()/2, centerPoint.y() - newWidget->height()/2);
```

You may consider using `frameGeometry()` instead of `geometry()`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/application-windows.html#window-geometry

Hope that helps.